# Jquery Ajax - Uncaught SyntaxError - Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I am trying to make an AJAX jsonp request to a temporary source of data for testing. This is the code I am using:

```
$('#search').click(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.test.com/v1/",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {q:$("#keyword").val()},
        timeout: 5000,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#content').fadeTo(500, 0.5);
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: '0px'
            }, 300);
        $('#content').html(data.objects[0].category+'<br>'+data.objects[0].company);
        },
        error: function (x, t, m) {
            if (t === "timeout") {
                alert("Request timeout");
            } else {
                alert('Request error');
            }
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#content').fadeTo(500, 1);
        }
    });
});
```

When ever I try and run the command I get the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

I am new to jquery and ajax generally, and this has me stumped. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That URL that you're using does not appear to be a JSONP service. It's returning a plain JSON structure, and that won't work for JSONP.

You'll either need to figure out an alternative API for that service that is JSONP, or else query it from your server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `JSONP` as datatype, its return from the server should be something like this

`jQuery111207659580435138196_1433210804043({"status" : "success"})`